# NodeJS array and firebase reference getting garbage collected

Tags: node.js, firebase, socket.io

I want to be able to create some firebase references when the first user connects to a socket.io room, and then listen to changes on those firebase references, and write to files.

Now my approach was to have a global Map object, then assign firebase references and filenames to arrays as part of an object. Then store the object, to the global map.
Unfortunately, the references are lost as soon as the function for first connection ends. I can see this by letting another user connect / refreshing the page and logging the global map.

Here is what my code looks like.

```js
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    io.to(socket.id).emit('create-room');
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId: string) => {
      socket.join(roomId);
      try {
        console.log(activeWorkers)
        if (!activeWorkers.get(roomId)) {
          // if not in global map, tell user he is first in room so that we can get additional info
          io.to(socket.id).emit('first-in-room');
        } else {
          console.log(activeWorkers.get(roomId));
        }
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    socket.on('create-worker', async (roomId: string, additionalInfo: string) => {
      // first user sent back additional info;
      let firebaseRefObj = new FirebaseRefObj(roomId, additionalInfo); // an object that stores the references and file paths

      activeWorkers.set(roomId, {
        id: roomId,
        worker: firebaseRefObj
      }); // store in global map
      firebaseRefObj.createRefs(); // create references, the references add initial values to firebase, then watch for changes to update local files.
    })
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      socket.removeAllListeners();
    });
  })
```

Comment: Ignore the entitled Javascript developer, he doesn't realize that redis also uses RAM. I want to know if your script is run on a dedicated VM or on Cloud Functions as Cloud Functions can also time out and isn't designed to persist data too long.

Comment: I dont really understand how any storage media can handle what I want, where I want to have active FIREBASE listeners. Which write data stored in firebase rtd to disk. 

I am currently testing on local machine, but plan to dockerize it when i want to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because socket.io functions don't persist their variables from within `on` events, if you are trying to access the `firebaseRefObj` at a later point, you must store it into an array or an object map so you can re-associate that user with it.

You could use the Room ID as you have and pass it as a name of the value in your list of references `{[roomId]: firebaseRefObj}`

Personally, I highly recommend an `enmap` for this use case, an `enmap` is like a C# dictionary for node.js. When you initiate your script and declare your variables, add a new enmap at the top to store your ref objects.

I believe the following will work:

```js
const Enmap = require("enmap");
const FirebaseRefs = new Enmap();

// ...
FirebaseRefs.set(RoomId, FirebaseRefsObj);
```

You can read the basics here: https://enmap.evie.dev/usage/basic

Source:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/enmap

Comment: Thing is I had a global Map() that I was assigning the firebaseRefsObj to.

Problem is, the firebaseRefsObj is still in memory, but the class contains three arrays, and all those arrays are empty. 1 array is an array of strings, and the other are firebase refs. I will give enmap a shot.

Comment: I see the reference to storing it in a global map, but you aren't passing the `firebaseRefObj` to it, only: `roomID` and `firepad` - so when `socket.on("create-worker")` resolves, it is lost

Comment: Oh I just noticed I had a bad refactoring error. Anyways, I updated my post. 

I am storing roomId and firebaseRefObj, then calling createRefs() which adds the firebase references with value handlers, to arrays in firebaseRefObj.  

It doesnt matter if I save first, then add refs, or the opposite. The array is empty for the second user/first user reload

Comment: you should be checking if the value exists before creating a new one then, no?
otherwise, this is a standard race condition

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with the client and how you are calling the socket connections, double-check your app flow 
and if garbage collection is still an issue: `worker: new FirebaseRefObj(roomId, additionalInfo);`

Comment: @DIGI_Byte `if (!activeWorkers.get(roomId)) {` is supposed to be the guard.

and yea I tried that already, the obj stays in memory, and is logged on a new user. But the array inside the class are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Enmap was a really good solution, but my problem lied with what I was using my firebase references with. I was internally using firepad, and it took itself along with the firebase reference out of scope.

Removing firepad fixed my issue.